# Connect DC 6-30V 1-Way Relay Module Power-off Trigger Delay Cycle Timer Switch with PIR Motion sensor?

Tags: sensor, relay, timer, delay, pir

I am trying to connect a [DC 6-30V](https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-6-30V-1-Way-Relay-Module-Power-off-Trigger-Delay-Cycle-Timer-Switch-US-Ship-/384587744862?mkcid=16&mkevt=1&_trksid=p2349624.m46890.l49286&mkrid=711-127632-2357-0) 1-Way Relay Module Power-off Trigger Delay Cycle Timer Switch with an [HC-SR501](https://www.ebay.com/itm/For-Arduino-Raspberry-pi-New-Tool-HC-SR501-Infrared-PIR-Motion-Sensor-Module-/393749882204?mkcid=16&mkevt=1&_trksid=p2349624.m46890.l49286&mkrid=706-127636-26712-0) Infrared PIR Motion Sensor Module.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The output of the motion sensor is only 3 V. Do you think it’s not enough voltage to trigger the module?

My issue is that the motion sensor is not triggering the module. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have included the links.. thanks

Comment: So did you find in the specs if the input works with what the output provides?

Comment: Yes it did. Second point in the specs : "Triggering signal source: high level trigger (3.0V-24V)".

Comment: It says high level trigger 3-24v and they don’t share ground

Comment: So where is the issue, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your breadboard 5V supply is off as indicated by the picture.

Also it reads that the supply voltage is 6..30V so it does not need to work with 5V you are feeding in.

Comment: It was on before and didn’t work either

Comment: You did not say that.

Comment: What do you think the issue though?

Comment: @K4ever Maybe 5V is not enough for a device that says it needs at least 6V?

Comment: I increase the input voltage but the problem the output will stay 3v, is there a way to increase the output voltage?